# WPF: Raise programmatically a SelectionChangedEvent with an object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, selectionchanged

`MouseDoubleClick` opens a new window in which I update the `DataTable` by changing the content of `TextBoxes`. After updating a `DataTable`, I need to raise a `SelectionChangedEvent` in order to update strings to the correct values (SelectionChangedEvent triggers when you select a row in the DataGrid). That would be simple enough, if I wasn't programmatically selecting the same row after refreshing the `DataGrid`, which means that the selection technically never changes and the values won't update unless I select another row.

I solved the issue by changing the index to -1 then changing it back to the previous value, but I would rather just call the handler directly `DG_Part_SelectionChanged();`. Refactoring the logic into a new function doesn't work.

```
    public void DG_Part_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentPartID != 0)
        {
            int lastId = CurrentPartID;
            EditWindow ew = new EditWindow(CurrentPartID)
            {
                Owner = this
            };
            ew.ShowDialog();
            if (Global.invokeDataGridParts == "yes")
            {
                // Refreshes the datagrid with an updated datatable
                InvokeDataGridPart();
                // Finds and selects the new index position of the modified row
                SqlPartsSetToRow(lastId);
                // Scrolls into view
                dg_part.ScrollToCenterOfView(dg_part.Items[dg_part.SelectedIndex]);
                // Highlights the row
                Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() =>
                {
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg_part.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg_part.SelectedIndex);
                    row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                }
                ));
                // Restores index so that you may re-select the previous selection correctly
                int saveIndex = dg_part.SelectedIndex;
                dg_part.SelectedIndex = -1;
                dg_part.SelectedIndex = saveIndex;
            }
        }
    }

   public void DG_Part_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        if (gd.SelectedItem is DataRowView row_selected)
        {
            Global.del = row_selected["DEL"].ToString();
            Global.delez = row_selected["DELEZ"].ToString();
            Global.cr_tu = row_selected["CRTU"].ToString();
            Global.st_clanov = row_selected["ST"].ToString();
            Global.lastnik = row_selected["LASTNIK"].ToString();
            Global.naslov = row_selected["NASLOV"].ToString();
            Global.ps = row_selected["PS"].ToString();
            Global.obmocje2 = row_selected["OBMOCJE"].ToString();
            Global.drzava = row_selected["DRZAVA"].ToString();
            Global.emso = row_selected["EMSO"].ToString();
            Global.maticna_st = row_selected["MATICNA"].ToString();
            Global.reference = row_selected["REFERENCE"].ToString();
            Global.opis = row_selected["OPIS"].ToString();
            Global.opomba = row_selected["OPOMBA"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's called first the `MouseDoubleClick`, then the `SelectionChanged`?

Comment: I mean, the content changes only in `MouseDoubleClick` or there's another method to update values inside the `DataTable`? Can you provide an example of the flow of events? For example, I click a button and `MouseDoubleClick` is called. If you want to take care of the value '-1', you can do in `DG_Part_SelectionChanged`: `if(dg_part.SelectedIndex == -1) return;`

Comment: @A.Wolf Please look at my answer. I think I solved it myself. Would appreciate a suggested edit or two, for further references.

Comment: What do you mean a suggested edit or two? How to improve your code?

Comment: How to properly format a question. I had a feeling it was hard to understand.

Comment: As I said, a good idea is to write something like this: _when I click on a button, `MouseDoubleClick` raised. What I want is that update the content of the table,_ It depends also on your problem. The idea is to give more information you can about your problem, so that people which look at your code can have more insights as possible to help you. If we can't understand the flow of the application, would be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change `DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;` into `DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)dg_part;` and refactor the logic:

```
    public void DG_Part_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DG_Part_Selection();
    }

    public void DG_Part_Selection()
    {
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)dg_part;
        if (gd.SelectedItem is DataRowView row_selected)
        {
            Global.del = row_selected["DEL"].ToString();
            Global.delez = row_selected["DELEZ"].ToString();
            Global.cr_tu = row_selected["CRTU"].ToString();
            Global.st_clanov = row_selected["ST"].ToString();
            Global.lastnik = row_selected["LASTNIK"].ToString();
            Global.naslov = row_selected["NASLOV"].ToString();
            Global.ps = row_selected["PS"].ToString();
            Global.obmocje2 = row_selected["OBMOCJE"].ToString();
            Global.drzava = row_selected["DRZAVA"].ToString();
            Global.emso = row_selected["EMSO"].ToString();
            Global.maticna_st = row_selected["MATICNA"].ToString();
            Global.reference = row_selected["REFERENCE"].ToString();
            Global.opis = row_selected["OPIS"].ToString();
            Global.opomba = row_selected["OPOMBA"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Then simply call the handler:

```
    public void DG_Part_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentPartID != 0)
        {
            int lastId = CurrentPartID;
            EditWindow ew = new EditWindow(CurrentPartID)
            {
                Owner = this
            };
            ew.ShowDialog();
            if (Global.invokeDataGridParts == "yes")
            {
                // Refreshes the datagrid with an updated datatable
                InvokeDataGridPart();
                // Finds and selects the new index position of the modified row
                SqlPartsSetToRow(lastId);
                // Scrolls into view
                dg_part.ScrollToCenterOfView(dg_part.Items[dg_part.SelectedIndex]);
                // Highlights the row
                Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() =>
                {
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg_part.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg_part.SelectedIndex);
                    row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                }
                ));
                // Restores index so that you may re-select the previous selection correctly
                DG_Part_Selection();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is what I was suggesting you ;-) I often use a solution like this.